# Using client side scripting to control an SAPUI5 app

Tags: javascript, sapui5

So, we have an existing app, which I think is built on sapui5 if I am not mistaken. It's pretty much a simple search function app. I reviewed the DOM and noted that the search box form has the ID of `#__xmlview0--searchField-F`, and the search box container including all is under `#__xmlview0--searchField` and the actual text entry area is under `#__xmlview0--searchField-I`. Essentially, it looks something like this - highly simplified:

```
<div id = "__xmlview0--searchField">
    <form id = "__xmlview0--searchField-F">
        <input type = "search" id = "__xmlview0--searchField-I" />
        <div id = "__xmlview0--searchField-search"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

There are two pages that I am interested in, one is the original start page for searching, and the other is the search page with results displayed, which also contains the same search box so that users can quickly perform another search. Lets call these `start page` and `results page`.

Since the app doesn't seem to take any QS for search strings, I was wanting to create a nested page where I can simply pass on the elements of searching into the app generated page, and display search results with one click, instead of having the users need to do them manually and transcribe things from one place to the search function.

I have attempted initially to simply change the value of the search box and then submit the search:

```
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-I").val("SOMETHING");
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-F").submit();
```

Such approach did not work. It appears that the submit will execute for the `start page`, but will not for the `results page`. But even with the start page where submit executed, the search text of "SOMETHING" has been lost for sure somehow. So I tried typing in text manually and only doing:

```
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-F").submit();
```

Which seems to show the submit button working (also only for `start page`, not for `results page`), though it appears that "SOMETHING" is still lost somehow even though I manually entered the text when executed in start page. Thinking something may be wrong with clicking the submit mechanism programatically, I tried only doing:

```
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-I").val("SOMETHING");
```

and then manually click the search execution icon (also tried pressing "enter"). But to my dismay, despite the DOM display the changes for the input search field properly, the search did not execute though the button blinked so I am sure I properly clicked it at least.

So I thought, maybe I need to trigger some kind of event before I start making changes to the search field to prompt proper event execution behind the scenes so that the input text will be recognized properly when changed:

```
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-I").focus();
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-I").val("SOMETHING");
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-I").focus();
$("#__xmlview0--searchField-F").submit();
```

But that did not work either. I am pulling my hairs out trying to figure out what may be going on. Can someone who knows the SAPUI5 stuff give me some insight? Am I doing something that is simply not possible under this environment?

Comment: In my opinion you are working in the wrong way. You should use models to pass content to search boxes, instead of pushing values inside them, SAPUI5 works in this way. Are you using XML views? Can you please post the view part related to these search pages?

Comment: I am not over the SAP app, but I think they are using XML views. The entire view part is quite long - is there something I should be looking for and post? Do you want the first line for view0 or so or something along those lines?

Comment: I think it would be interesting to see the part of the XML view containing the searchfield you are trying to fill.

Comment: Looks like UI5... Don't try to manipulate the framework using the DOM directly, those ID's are all generated and could change (not to mention connected to "ui5 controls"). There should be an XML view and a corresponding Controller somewhere

Comment: Hi, before trying out my workaround you should read the other posts. instead of e.g. $("").submit() you can try 
let var1 = jQuery.sap.byId("#view--id"); 
$(var1).submit();
PS: jquery.sap namespace is deprecated since 1.58